# In Windows OS, some background process consuming 75 MB Network data ( BroadBand wastage) everyday. How can I find that background process?

Tags: networking, sniffing

I am using limited BroadBand ( I can use up to 3GB per month). BroadBand company charges extra money if I use beyond 3 GB.

Everyday one ( or more)  background process utilizing 75 MB of Internet Data. I have been monitoring Internet data usage through NET METER  tool.

Initially I suspected AVG anti virus S/W so I uninstalled it, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Note: I have closed all Net browsers to confirm background process network utilization.

Can you please tell me , how can I identify background process which is utilizing 75 MB on everyday ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have Windows 7, you can look in the Resource Monitor to see what applications are using bandwidth. Open the task manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>), go to the Performance tab, and click on "Resource Monitor". On the "Network" tab, click on the column heading "Total (B/sec)" to sort the processes by total usage. This will also show you what server the process is connecting to, which can be useful for determining what a process may be doing.

[image: windows 7 resource monitor network]

Answer (score 0):

You could try a software designed to that:

http://www.sharewareplaza.com/network-traffic-monitor-download_33543.html

This one shows network usage by process.

Comment: @Pedro, thank you very much. This tool will solve my problem.

Comment: @siva could you please mark as answer, then? :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Update tends to use some bandwidth. Other software that could also consume bandwidth could be viruses. Use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to monitor the network traffic on your Network Interfaces

Also, you could use a little tool called [process monitor](http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/ProcessMonitor.zip) to monitor the most active disc IO on your PC. The latter one I'd recommend using while your PC is completely idle!

Answer (score 0):

you can use NetLimiter.

http://www.netlimiter.com/

the free version will show a list of your processes and their bandwidth usage. =)